# tinyMCE upload image to cloud instead of server

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tinyMCE 4.x latest version and it has Moxie Manager integrated, but it uploads my image files directly on server. I need to avoid that because my website is hosted at AppFog where is not possible to store information because it's PaaS. Can anyone tell me is it possible to redirect the image upload to cloud service or other storage method capable with AppFog or maybe Heroku, because I found that Moxie Manager wants 700Euro to give me plugin for image upload to Amazon S3, but 700Euro is impossible to pay. I will be very thankful for other plugins that can be integrated to tinyMCE its not necessary to use Moxie Manager ( it looks great but this price... )